# How to get PAM30 to work (on Windows7)

Tags: python, windows-7, pamie

**Background**: 
I am trying to create a program with which I can log in on a website. First I have used IEControler. However the particular site on which I am trying to log in has one particular feature which does not work with IEC.

**Problems**
After some searching I found PAM30. This module seems to have more options so I wanted try this. However I cannot get PAM30 to work proberly.
Apart from navigating I cannot get anything to work. I did a lot of searching on google and tried lots of different solutions but not one works.

**PAM30 and WINDOWS 7**
So what I am wondering is there anybody who has used PAM30 with succes in combination with Windos 7? And if so what versions of Python, PyWin and IE did you use?

Comment: please provide some of the things you tried, refer to: [whathaveyoutried.com](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: The error I got most often is the TyperError. According to some comments this is caused by errors in module that you are calling (=PAM30). So I add my code to the PAM30 module. No result.

Comment: Another suggestion was to change to compatibility view of internet explorer. -> use the compatibility view for all websites. No result

Comment: Another suggestion was to install Internet Explorer 8.0. -> I get the message that this is not possible.

Comment: Again another suggestion is that PAM30 can only be used with Python 3.0 or above. So I installed it -> No result

Comment: Another suggestion was the opposite PAM30 is not for Python 3.x. So I installed 2.7.3 again. -> No result (I did those installations a couple of times to make sure)

Comment: Going to all possible errors, trying to understand the possible solution and trying to apply it is very very difficult. Also I noticed that solutions may result in new problems. Therefore I would like to shift my focus from what is going wrong to what works on the same system that I have. I have Windows 7, I will not change that but if someone gotten PAM30 to work on this I would like to know which versions (of Python, Pywin and PAM) he used so I can do the same.

Comment: you should delete all these comments and put them into your question. preferably also with some of the code you have tried.

Comment: No. I have seen examples of code which works for other people. So I know the code is not the problem. The problem is to find out when (with which configuration) it works.